# How to fix "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Item 1.1" at path "_id" for model "Item"" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on a project and i need to add a document inside an array that is inside another document, but everytime i try i get this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Item 1.1" at path "_id" for model "Item"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4361:21)
    at _update (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4213:11)
    at model.Query.Query.updateOne (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4112:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3780:16)
    at Function.updateOne (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3716:10)
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\main.js:77:22
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4889:21
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4400:11
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\kareem\index.js:136:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"Item 1.1"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'Item 1.1',
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:279:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1091:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1526:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1516:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1493:20)
      at cast (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:331:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4766:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1843:10)
      at model.Query._updateThunk (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3710:8)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3842:23)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _updateOne] (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
      at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

I have tried fixing it but is still doesn't work. Here is where the problem is:

```
app.post('/addinitem', function (req, res) {

    tabb += 1;

    tex = req.body.addtoitem;

    const item2 = new Item({
        name: namee,
        initem: [],
        text: tex,
        tab: tabb
    });

    Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundITems) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundITems) {
                var itemid = req.body.addtoitem;
                console.log(itemid);
                Item.updateOne({ _id: itemid }, { $push: { initem: item2 } }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                console.log("added initem");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the full code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/appline", { useUnifiedTopology: true }, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const itemSchema = {
    name: String,
    initem: Array,
    text: String,
    tab: Number
}

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

const items = [];
const tabs = [];

var foundItemList1;

var namee = "";
var tabb = 0;

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    namee = req.body.name;
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (namee == "") {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundItemList) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else if (foundItemList) {
                console.log(namee);
                console.log("Found ITems: " + foundItemList);
                for (var i = 0; i < foundItemList.length; i++) {
                    foundItemList1 = foundItemList[i].initem;
                }
                res.render('main', { item: foundItemList, foundItems: foundItemList1 });
            }
        });
    }
});

app.post('/addinitem', function (req, res) {

    tabb += 1;

    tex = req.body.addtoitem;

    const item2 = new Item({
        name: namee,
        initem: [],
        text: tex,
        tab: tabb
    });

    Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundITems) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundITems) {
                var itemid = req.body.addtoitem;
                console.log(itemid);
                Item.updateOne({ _id: itemid }, { $push: { initem: item2 } }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                console.log("added initem");
            }
        }
    });

});

app.post('/add', function (req, res) {
    const item = req.body.newItem;
    console.log(item);
    items.push(item);
    const item1 = new Item({
        name: namee,
        initem: [],
        text: item
    });
    item1.save();
    console.log(item1);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000.');
});
```

Here is where the error is in the html:

```
<div class="card shadow-sm w-75 mx-auto py-1 px-2 my-1 containe h-auto"
                    style=" height: 40px; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <div class="row-cols-3" style="height: auto; vertical-align: middle; display: flex; padding: 10px;">
                        <div style=" height: 25px; float: left; display: flex;" class="my-auto w-75">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checked" id="" class="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; flo">
                            <p class="text-primary mx-3">
                                <%= items.text %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: fit-content; height: 25px;" class="my-auto btn-group mx-5">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger col mx-auto"
                                style="width: 25px; height: 25px; border-radius: 0; margin-right: 0px; padding: 0; font-size: large;">-</button>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary col mx-auto"
                                style="width: 25px; margin-left: 2px; height: 25px; border-radius: 0; border-top-right-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0; font-size: large;"
                                data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">+</button>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <form action="/addinitem" method="POST">
                            <div class="card" style="display: block;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-25">+</button>
                                <input type="text" name="addtoitem" id="" class="form-control w-75 float-end">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you assuming the user input `addtoitem` value to be of type mongodb ObjectId, if so it should be something like `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011` which is  a hexadecimal string, unless you overide the default  one when you define `Item` schema, if you want to update item by name why not use `Item.updateOne({ name: namee },`, instead of querying database twice.

Answer (score 0):

Convert _id into objectID, you can do it like this.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;

_id: ObjectId(itemid )
```